# PHPUnit is reporting errors instead of recognizing assertFalse()

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I am attempting to test a simple Laravel model which has required "password" and "email" properties. My test reads as follows…

```
public function testEmailIsRequired() {
    $user = new User;
    $user->password = 'derp';

    // should not save
    $this->assertFalse($user->save());

}
```

Rather than correctly agree that "this doesn't work" and a successful test, I’m getting…

```
1) UserTest::testEmailIsRequired 
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
19 NOT NULL constraint failed: users.email 
(SQL: insert into "users" ("password", "updated_at", "created_at") 
values (derp, 2014-09-26 15:27:07, 2014-09-26 15:27:07))
[...]
FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I’m afraid that I’m a total novice here. It seems to me that PHPUnit ought to be suppressing the database driver’s own error reporting and just accepting "false"… help?

Comment: What does the code for `User::save()` look like?  If the email is required shouldn't your code have exited rather than trying to save to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is looking for the function to return false.  Any other errors generated in your function will still be returned, since you are calling the function.

```
public function testEmailIsRequired() 
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->password = 'derp';

    // should not save
    $this->assertFalse($user->save());

}

public function testMockSaveWorks()
{
    $Mock = $this->getMock('User', array('save'));

    // Set up the expectation for the getResult() method 
    $Mock->expects($this->any())
         ->method('save')
         ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $this->assertTrue($Mock->save());
}

class User()
{
...
    public function save()
    {
        if( is_null($this->email) )
            return false;

        ...
        return true;
    }
 }
```

You should then use Mocks to remove the actual save() function and its tie in to your database, and have the mock return true to pretend to save the record to show that you have tested the module.

Comment: I see. I thought all of this functionality was built-in to Eloquent.

Thank you Steven & Schleis.